# Webpack: Do not parse specific html tag

Tags: html, django, webpack, django-templates

I'm using webpack to build html templates using Django's templating language. Django templates contain variables and tags using `{{ }}` and `{% %}` syntax. Webpack has ignored these just fine and built the html templates as expected, except when parsing `srcset` tags.

Webpack errors when it tries to parse the following html:
`<source srcset="{% static 'images/my-image.png' %}">`

I'd like webpack to either ignore all srcset tags completely, or have some sort of `# noqa` equivalent which makes webpack simply not make changes to this row of the file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is the best solution, but one workaround which feels very hacky, is to create a global template variable that returns an empty string.

The template tag can be inserted between `src` and `set` so that webpack doesn't parse it as a `srcset` tag. Then when django renders the template, it replaces the template variable with an empty string (nothing).

```py
# context processor
def dummy(request):
    return {"pass": ""}

# add the context processor to your templates in settings.py 
TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["CONTEXT_PROCESSORS"].append(<path/to/dummy-context-processpr>)
```

```html
src{{pass}}set="{% static 'images/my-image.webp' %} 480w, {% static 'images/my-image-800.webp' %} 800w"
```